# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'COL' to data type int

Tags: c#

Estou tentando cadastrar um projeto em uma determinada área, porem toda vez que tento cadastrar ele retorna uma exceção.

Exceção:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'COL' to data type
>   int.

Meu controller:

```
// GET: Projeto/Create
public ActionResult Create()
    {
      ViewBag.proArea = new SelectList(db.tblArea, "areIdArea", "areArea");
      return View();
    }

// POST: Projeto/Create
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "proIdProjeto,proNome,proArea")] tblProjeto tblProjeto)
   {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
         db.tblProjeto.Add(tblProjeto);
         db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }

      ViewBag.proArea = new SelectList(db.tblArea, "areIdArea", "areArea", tblProjeto.proArea);
        return View(tblProjeto);
     }
```

Minha Classe:

```
public partial class tblProjeto
    {

        [Key]
        public int proIdProjeto { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Inform o nome deo projeto")]
        [Display(Name = "Nome")]
        public string proNome { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "informe a area")]
        [Display(Name = "Area")]
        public Nullable<int> proArea { get; set; }

        public virtual tblArea tblArea { get; set; }
     }
```

Eu realmente não sei como arrumar, pesquisei por aqui, mas não encontrei nenhum exemplo que chegasse próximo da minha necessidade.
Gostaria de saber por que fica dando esta exceção e como posso arruma-la?
Peço a ajuda de vcs e me desculpe caso algo esteja errado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na sua View, o campo onde está sendo preenchido com 'COL' no Visual Studio pode estar como `string`, mas ao mandar o comando para inserir no banco, ha um conflito de tipos, provavelmente no banco esta como `int`... Ou se estiver mandando como `FK`, você deve estar passando o `value` ao invés do `ID`.

Verifique as tipagem dos dados, se caso precisar mandar para a `View` de uma outra forma, crie uma `ViewModel` assim você pode fazer, de grosso modo, do jeito que quiser...